# Delaying a Javascript code snipped for a specific amount of time in one line

Tags: javascript, wordpress, delay, contact-form-7

A wordpress contact form plugin (contact form 7) allows us to use a snippet after the form is sent. The help states that we can use it like this:

```
on_sent_ok: "alert('sent ok');"
```

I'm using this snippet, to hide a div after the message is sent successfuly and it works:

```
on_sent_ok: $(".popmake").hide();
```

What I need to do is make this action to be taken after  a specific amount of time like 2000 miliseconds after the message is sent (or the send button is clicked, whatever). Is it possible to do it in one line ?

I've almost no knowledge of Javascript, I got this line from other questions in here but couldn't figure out to delay it. I appreciate all helps.

Cheers!

Solved:

```
on_sent_ok: setTimeout(function() {$(".popmake").hide();},2000);
```

Thanks a lot @jordumus!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {$(".popmake").hide();},2000);` is technically 1 line as well.

Comment: @Jordumus Thanks a lot, worked like a charm!